# Android: Should I use views or activities for this tab? Can I use a shared layout for the tabs?

Tags: android

I have been reading your posts and they are very helpful. However, I really need your experienced advise in this and what would you do if you were me.
I am doing and application in which is has 4 tabs. The layout of the 4 tabs is similar (a table that has values in its cells and 3 buttons, and textview). The only thing that changes from one tab to another is the table values and textview. However, I need to share data between the tabs as the values on each tab are dependent on previous tab

How do you think I should approach? I have been reading that using views is generally recommended over activites. Can I use the same view layout for all the tabs?

Please any help on how you would design it will be great. I am on 2.1 and targetting pretty much all platforms .THANK U

PS: I tried (as an example) having textview under the framelayout, but the problem is that changing the text in Java code will make the textview changes in all the tabs. For some reason, I am feeling that having 4 text views (one for each tab) is kinda redundant and bad design but I dont know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this by defining a layout, and using that same layout in each of your tabs. E.g.

```
public class MyTabActivity1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.tab_layout);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem with that (from my limited knowledge) is that if I use the same layout then the same textviews (table cells and other table views) have the same ID. Meaning that if I change a text view on 3, then the same textview will change on tab 1, 2, and 4 and I dont want that because that tabs have to have different text values.

Comment: Yes, they will have the same ids, but that's OK. setContentView() inflates your layout, creating a set of View objects for the activity to use. Each activity will have its own set of View objects. A simple example of this behavior is a ListView, where all the items use the same layout, but display different data.

Comment: Blackrider,Thanks for your answer. I am still confused about something. So When I create the tab with the same XML layout, you agreed that the contents will have the same ID. Therefore, if I do findViewById and give it an ID of the textview, then it will return me the textview ON THAT activity? or would it be shared textview (kind of a static variable across the tabs)

Comment: I think it's the former. There is no requirement for the view ids to be unique across your app (See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). As long as your ids are unique within the same activity, you should be good.

Comment: Hmm. So at the end of the day, I am creating an activity for each tab. Not one activity with multiple views. I just noticed something. If you call findViewById then you are calling this on an activity not on a view. Meaning that it it will return the view corresponding for a specific Id for THAT activity. And Since I have ONE activity for all the tabs, then all the tabs will sue the same textView if I call findViewById. Thus I would Ihave to either go with multiple activites if I am to use one XML layout file, or make 4 copies of the XML layout with different IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for TabHost and TabWidget to solve your problem. Below is a sample demo for with the implementation. `Tab_Layout.xml`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="4dip">

                <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0" android:orientation="horizontal" />

                <FrameLayout android:id="@+android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
    </LinearLayout>
```